# How to fix ''generator' object is not subscriptable" error when reading fasta file with BioPython

Tags: python, biopython, fasta

I am trying to open and read a fasta file and use only the first line from the input.  Currently, I'm calling the first line and appending it to a list to use in a later function.  However, I'm getting an error that generator object is not subscriptable.

```
def unam_base_plot(in_file, out_file):

    unam_rna = SeqIO.parse(in_file, 'fasta')
    rna_x = []
    for rna in unam_rna:
        rna_x = unam_rna[0:][0]
        rna_x.append(SeqRecord(rna_x, id = seq_rna.id))
    SeqIO.write(rna_x, out_file, 'fasta')
```

Here is what the fasta file looks like:

```
>seq_000
RSKKCMWRMRRAACKRWUSRSWSK

>seq_001
GCAGAAUGAAUCGAUGGCGCCUGU

>seq_002
UACGGGAUCACCUAGGCACGUUUC

>seq_003
GAAAGGAGACAAGAGGGUAGCCUU
```

And I want it to return the sequence from seq_000.

Comment: Hi Ellie, you are dealing with a generator, so you can't use subscripting `[]`. Looks like the offending line is `rna_x = unam_rna[0:][0]`. Instead, refer to your loop variable `rna`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question and code are confusing as to what you want -- you seem to want output to a file but also to a list to use in a later function.  The primary problem I see with your code is `rna_x` appears to be two different variables with the same name!  But there are other issues.  Let's work through some examples:

Parse an input FASTA file, generating an output FASTA file with just the first sequence from the input file:

```
def unam_base_plot(in_file, out_file):

    for record in SeqIO.parse(in_file, 'fasta'):

        SeqIO.write(record, out_file, 'fasta')

        break  # we only want the first one!
```

Relative to your example input, the output of this routine would be a file containing:

```
>seq_000
RSKKCMWRMRRAACKRWUSRSWSK
```

If we want *just* the sequence data in the output, and not the FASTA header, we'd change the line:

```
SeqIO.write(record, out_file, 'fasta')
```

to instead be:

```
with open(out_file, 'w') as output:
    print(record.seq, file=output)
```

Since we're no longer creating a FASTA file but simply text.  If instead, we don't want to write output to a file but rather store the first sequence in the FASTA file to a global list:

```
rna_x = []

def unam_base_plot(in_file):

    for record in SeqIO.parse(in_file, 'fasta'):

        rna_x.append(record.seq)

        break  # we only want the first one!
```

Given your example input, our global list `rna_x` would now contain one item:

```
[Seq('RSKKCMWRMRRAACKRWUSRSWSK', SingleLetterAlphabet())]
```

after the call, but would eventually contain others if the function were called on more input files.  If we want just the raw sequence in our global list, and not a BioPython sequence object, we can change the line:

```
rna_x.append(record.seq)
```

to instead be:

```
rna_x.append(str(record.seq))
```

Then `rna_x` would contain:

```
['RSKKCMWRMRRAACKRWUSRSWSK']
```